# docker build issue with docker file: Jobber not working after adding a package

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm still learning all this stuff around docker. Now I have an issue that I don't understand. Maybe one of you can explain to me, what I did wrong.

I want to schedule some SQL scripts with jobber. Therefore I need to add the MYSQL-Client package into a jobber image.

Docker file:

```
FROM jobber:latest
User root

COPY install-packages.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./install-packages.sh
RUN ./install-packages.sh
```

install-packages.sh

```
apk update
apk upgrade
apk add mysql-client
rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
```

My docker build command:

```
docker build . -t jobbermysql:20210110
```

Docker-Compose file to run the container:

```
version: '3'

services:
  jobbermysql:
    image: jobbermysql:20210110
    container_name: jobbermysqlcompose
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/docker/datapath/jobber/jobberuser:/home/jobberuser
```

The docker build works fine. but when I run an instance of my image jobbermysql:20210110 jobber always reports:

```
jobbermysqlcompose | User root doesn't own jobfile
```

If I try to get some additional information / jobs via direct access to the running container (e.g. a jobber init command to understand the issues)

```
/home/jobberuser # jobber init
Jobber doesn't seem to be running for user root.
(No socket at /var/jobber/0/cmd.sock.): stat /var/jobber/0/cmd.sock: no such file or directory
```

If I restart the “old” default jobber version (without my modification of mysql-client) it’s working fine. And they both use the same volume mapping. So I think I have destroyed something in the docker build process.

```
version: '3'

services:
  jobbermysql:
    image: jobber:latest
    container_name: jobbermysqlcompose
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /home/docker/datapath/jobber/jobberuser:/home/jobberuser
```

Can somebody give me an hint?

Many Thanks and Kind regads
Holger

Answer (score 0):

Jobber itself seems to be quite specific about the required file permissions of the .jobber file. [Jobber's documentation](https://dshearer.github.io/jobber/doc/v1.4/#jobfile) states the following:

> Jobfiles must be owned by the user who owns the home directory that
> contains them, and their permissions must not allow the owning group
> or any other users to write to them (i.e., the permission bits must
> exclude 022)

Therefore, we need to set the file permissions of the mounted file accordingly. As the official docker is running as [USER jobberuser](https://github.com/dshearer/jobber-docker/blob/cd07d76987097b5389aa9be5f48df041aa74d699/alpine3.11/Dockerfile#L24), we need to set the file permissions accordingly:

```sh
chown 1000:1000 jobber-jobs.yml
chmod 600 jobber-jobs.yml
```

In your case, you switched to `USER root`, but did not switch back after installing the packages. The following Dockerfile & docker-compose.yml did work for me:

```sh
FROM jobber

USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client

USER jobberuser
```

```yml
version: '3'

services:
  cron:
    image: mysql-jobber
    build: ./build
    volumes:
      - ./jobber-jobs.yml:/home/jobberuser/.jobber:ro
```